# Domain of the composition of functions

Tags: functions, radicals

> If $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x-1}$, find $f(g(x))$ and specify the domain.

**My solution**

$$
f(g(x)) = \left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)^2 = x-1,
$$
Domain: $x$ such that $x$ is any real number.

Solution at the back of the book states that the domain is, $x$ such that $x \ge 1$.

Now I understand why that is the domain for $g(x)$, for any number less than 1 would make $g(x)$ negative and the square root of a negative number is an imaginary number.

But, that is not the cases with $f(g(x))$. When is $(\sqrt{x-1})^2$ not a real number? isn't any input valid?

Comment: To evaluate $f[g(0)]$, you **must first** evaluate $g(0)$.  If $g(0)$ is undefined (within the realm of Real Analysis, rather than Complex Analysis), then *by definition*, $f[g(0)]$ **can not be defined**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have to differentiate between
$$
f(g(x)) = \left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)^2
$$
and $h(x) = x-1$. For $h(x)$, indeed the domain are all reals, but $f(g(x))$ is defined to only take the *output* of $g(x)$, so you have to go through $g(x)$ first, resulting in the domain being $x \ge 1$.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to put the answer, which has already been given, is that it’s *not* always the case that $\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)^2=x-1$! This equation holds if and only if $x\ge 1$. If $x=0$, for instance, then the left hand is undefined while the right is $-1$. So it’s incorrect to simplify this composite to $x-1$ without explicitly restricting the domain.

Comment: +1, a very insightful way of formulating the answer

Comment: "If x=0, for instance, then the left hand is undefined while the right is −1." What? The square root of -1 is i, and i^2 is -1.

Comment: @nick012000 In talking about functions in the American-style high school math curriculum we exclusively discuss functions with real inputs and outputs. Anyway, it is not true that $\sqrt{-1}=i$. As you know $-i$ is also a square root of $-1$, and there is no mathematically meaningful difference between them. In particular there is no preferred square root function defined on the complex numbers. (The function giving $\sqrt z$ a nonnegative imaginary part exists, but is discontinuous and rarely useful.) For this and other reasons we study the real valued square root function instead.

Comment: @KevinArlin: Who says that a discontinuous square-root function on $ℂ$ minus some ray from the origin (say the negative reals) is rarely useful? From what I recall, it seems to play a key role in the proof of the Riemann mapping theorem!